# How do I get my PS4 controller driver to work on a PC?

Tags: usb, drivers, game-controller

When I use my PS4 controller with my computer it doesn't work and in device manager there is no HID compliant game controller driver.

It worked before I upgraded to Windows 10 but now DS4 doesn't show my controller.

Comment: also it was very picky with the naming

Comment: Additional information should typically be added to the original question. Also yes, you will likely need a lot more details to get the best help. What software were you using? How did you pair it? What version of Windows did it work on? etc etc - Admitting to laziness but posting it anyway doesn't show much effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DS4Windows](http://ds4windows.com/). It contains the drivers you'll need and give you a lot of other options.